# Following Create a web API with ASP.NET Core and MongoDB: Problem with MvcJsonOptions with definition of UseMemberCasing()

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-crud-operations-service-1)

I was following the documentation setting up a mongodb with .net core web api. Everything is working fine up until one of the last steps. **Configure JSON serialization options**. It seems to be incorrect but I may be missing something. Here is total code of my Startup.cs file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using BooksApi.Models;
using BooksApi.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace BooksApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>(
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(BookstoreDatabaseSettings)));

            services.AddSingleton<IBookstoreDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

            services.AddSingleton<BookService>();

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.UseMemberCasing())
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```cs
  services.AddMvc()
          .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```